# ¿Cómo convertir application/x-www-form-urlencoded a diccionario en python?

Tags: python, diccionarios

Tengo un contenido tipo application/x-www-form-urlencoded como cadena en python:

'filters={"process":{"id":1,"name":"**Action&Validation**"},"dimension":[]}&action=123'

Dentro del valor de la clave filters se encuentra una **&** y al tratar de dividir cada registro del formulario por & da una salida erronea. Este solo es un ejemplo, debo procesar muchos contenidos de este tipo.

¿Existe alguna forma genérica de ignorar estos caracteres a la hora de transformar la cadena a diccionario?

Comment: Cuando caes en este tipo de cosas, la mejor opción es recurrir a un parser bien diseñado en lugar de hacer cosas como usar regex o metodos de cadena. No se mucho del tema, pero quizá te sea util [urllib.parse.parse_qs](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs). Como urllib viene en la librería estandar, no hace falta instalar nada c:

Comment: Posdata: Probé tu cadena con dicha función y no parece dar problemas al parser (aunque no tengo idea de si es lo que buscas).

Comment: ¿O sea que quieres ignorar los "&" que ocurren como parte de un string dentro del dato?

Comment: Mandar json url encoded es tremendo anti-pattern, yo que tu empujo por mandarlo en el body y ocupar el content type correcto: `application/json`

Answer (score 0):

La función `parse` toma una cadena de texto conteniendo una o mas líneas de código Python separadas por "&" y retorna una lista con las líneas separadas. La función omite examinar dentro de las cadenas:

```
def parse(linea):
    start = 0
    idx = 0
    salida = []
    while idx < len(linea):
        if linea[idx] == '"':
            idx += 1
            while linea[idx] != '"':
                idx += 1
        if linea[idx] == '&':
            salida.append(linea[start:idx])
            idx += 1
            start = idx
        else:
            idx += 1
    salida.append(linea[start:idx])
    return salida
```

Nota: se supone que el contenido de `linea` es código Python válido (todos los strings están bien terminados).

Pasando

```
'filters={"process":{"id":1,"name":"Action&Validation"},"dimension":[]}&action=123'
```

como parámetros, obtenemos esta lista de salida:

```
['filters={"process":{"id":1,"name":"Action&Validation"},"dimension":[]}', 'action=123']
```

Para incorporar el diccionario y la variable al programa, se usa `exec()`

#### Demo

```
def parse(linea):
    start = 0
    idx = 0
    salida = []
    while idx < len(linea):
        if linea[idx] == '"':
            idx += 1
            while linea[idx] != '"':
                idx += 1
        if linea[idx] == '&':
            salida.append(linea[start:idx])
            idx += 1
            start = idx
        else:
            idx += 1
    salida.append(linea[start:idx])
    return salida


linea = 'filters={"process":{"id":1,"name":"Action&Validation"},"dimension":[]}&action=123'
for cmd in parse(linea):
    exec(cmd)
print(f"{filters}")
print(filters["process"])
print(filters["process"]["name"])
print(f"{action}")
```

produce:

```
{'process': {'id': 1, 'name': 'Action&Validation'}, 'dimension': []}
{'id': 1, 'name': 'Action&Validation'}
Action&Validation
123

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Yo lo que haría para hacer más segura la forma de obtener el diccionario es quitar programaticamente la parte donde se declara la variable ("filters=", si es que es posible) y al resto de la cadena aplicar [ast.literal_eval](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval). Recomiendo esto por que exec es inseguro debido a que con él se puede ejecutar código arbitrario.